# the sequence of one-line code of Reverse Words in a string on leetcode

Tags: java

I have a small question about one answer of this problem.
the problem is like

Given an input string, reverse the string word by word.

For example,
Given s = "the sky is blue",
return "blue is sky the".

The answer is

```
public class Solution {
public String reverseWords(String s) {
     s = s.trim();
return helper(s,0).toString();}

private StringBuilder helper(String s, int index){
if(index>=s.length())
    return new StringBuilder(); 
StringBuilder cur = new StringBuilder();
int lastIndex = index;
while(index < s.length() && s.charAt(index)!=' ')
{
    cur.append(s.charAt(index++));
}
while(index < s.length() && s.charAt(index)==' ')
    index++;
if(lastIndex == 0)
    return helper(s,index).append(cur);
return helper(s,index).append(cur).append(' ');}
```

I got a question about the last line of this code. why append(cur) is before append(' ')?    shouldn't it be after?

Comment: Why don't you run the code, and tell us what you discover by switching the append methods?

Comment: for example the test case is '    a     b  ' the expect answer is 'b a'. while if i change the sequence it's like' ba'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this part of the code :

```
   if(lastIndex == 0)
       return helper(s,index).append(cur);
   return helper(s,index).append(cur).append(' ');
```

The condition `(lastIndex == 0)` is true in the first call to helper, in which case `cur` contains the first word, and `helper(s,index)` returns the remaining words in reverse order.

Since you append, in this case, the first word to the rest of the reversed `StringBuilder` without adding a space, this means that `helper(s,index)` must append a space after the reversed sub-string.

For example, suppose you have a String :

One Two Three

`helper(s,index)` must return "Three Two ", to which you append "One" to get the reversed String.

The next call to helper would return "Three ", to which you append "Two" and then a space.

The next call returns an empty StringBuilder, to which you append "Three" and then a space.

You could replace the 3 lines above with this single line :

```
return helper(s,index).append(' ').append(cur);
```

However, in this case the output will have an extra space in the beginning, since the last call to `helper` returns an empty StringBuilder, so if you append a space after it, that space would be the first character of the output.

You can add a different condition to eliminate that extra space :

```
StringBuilder sub = helper(s,index);
if (sub.length() > 0)
   sub.append(' '); // append a space only if it's not the 
                    // first char of the output
return sub.append(cur);
```